# Can't set default servers in ERC layer

Tags: spacemacs, erc

My user-config looks following:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '((erc :variables
      erc-server-list
      '(("chat.freenode.net"
         :port "6697"
         :ssl t
         :nick "siulkilulki")))))
)
```

According to point 3.4 in http://spacemacs.org/layers/+chat/erc/README.html
it should set default servers, but when I press `<leader>aiD` I get `you must define erc-server-list`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` should be set up in 
`defun dotspacemacs/layers ()`. Moving code there solves problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when ERC starts it doesn't actually use the default servers unless you tell it to. Having two possibilities for default servers seems odd.

`M-m a-i-D` (it has to be a capitalized D) starts the default servers for me. Anything else starts on freenode.net with port 6667

For reference in my `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` I have the following format for my default server:

```
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '((erc :variables
          erc-server-list
          '(("irc.example.com"
               :port "6770"
               :ssl t
               :nick "nick"
               :password "password"))
          ))
```

UPDATE: What I ended up doing was making my own key setting to join the IRC server I wanted (C-c i):

```
  (global-set-key "\C-ci" (lambda () (interactive)
            (erc-tls :server "irc.example.com"
         :port "6779"
         :nick "my_username"
         :password "my_password")))
```